# Send Email - ESMTP Remote Server - Access Denied, but works for coworker

Tags: email, smtp, access-denied

I'm trying to send an email to a client, with an address @comcast.com

Within 4 seconds I get an email in my Inbox saying the message failed delivery.

A coworker sitting 10 feet away from me can send emails to this address successfully.  We are on the same domain and network.

```
Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:

xxxxx-xxxx@comcast.com  (yes, the name has a hyphen in it)

A problem occurred while delivering this message to this email address. Try sending this message again. If the problem continues, please contact your helpdesk.

The following organization rejected your message: ESMTP.

xxxxx-xxxx@comcast.com

ESMTP

Remote Server returned '<ESMTP #5.0.0 smtp;550 Mailbox unavailable or access denied - <xxxxx-xxxxx@comcast.com>>'
```

If any further information is needed please let me know.

---

Does this seem like a problem at the clients end or on our side?

Any ideas as to the cause? I don't see any detail about my access was denied...  no space, spam, blacklist, etc.?

Comment: Are you sure the recipient's address is in the comcast.com domain, and not in the comcast.net domain?  Customers of Comcast usually have an email address in the comcast.net domain.  Comcast uses comcast.com for their corporate email addresses.

Comment: @mti2935 That was it!  Odd that all of the emails show up as .com, but when switched manually to .net, they are sent and received.  thanks!

Comment: That's good news.  But, are you saying that emails from this comcast user show that they are from user@comcast.com instead of user@comcast.net?  If so, then perhaps this user entered their email address incorrectly in their mail client?

Comment: Correct.  Could be, was just notified they set up their "email system" in the last week... probably still figuring things out :-P